# Can the same 3V source be used for 2 different circuits

Tags: microcontroller, power-electronics

I'm trying to combine 2 circuits on a micro:bit - one to operate a PWM motor and the other to drive a 7 segment display.  I'm doing this on a Kitronik breakout board https://www.kitronik.co.uk/pdf/5601_edge_connector_breakout_board_for_the_bbc_microbit_datasheet_1_0.pdf

The 7 segment display has a 5V pin but seems to work from a 3V source provided by the micro:bit.

I don't know much about electronics so I thought I'd ask this while trying to figure out how to rearrange the components so that everything fits on the breadboard.

The two circuits work individually and both require a 3V source.  There are two 3V pins on the breakout board.  I've looked at various projects but I haven't found one where they're driving 2 components off the 3V source.

The question is: Would it be OK to use one pin for the PWM motor and the other for the 7 segment display or should I power one of them from a battery?

Comment: The **usual problem** is long power supply wires vulnerable to voltage drop shared by both controller and motor.  The motor's startup current causes a voltage drop, browning out the controller and causing a crash or reboot. The cure is separate (redundant) power supply wires for the controller, so the voltage drop only happens on the motor's supply wires, not the controller's.

Comment: The supply wires are about 2-3 inches and quite fine.  I don't know whether that is considered long or short.

Comment: oh that's fine, I'm talking cases where it was 6' or more and also too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

You have to take into account that the current supplied by the power source is (more than) the combined current need of the motor and the display. Note that the motor may use initially/during starting or accelerating more current.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer of Michel, if the power rail of the motor is also connected to this supply, you should make sure that you have enough capacitance close to the motor as it (depending on the model) can draw a lot of current on start-up, threfore dropping the supply voltage. The capacitance acts as some sort of energy buffer for the initial operation of the motor.